# I can't upload files larger than 50MB on Vimeo with Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, vimeo-api

When the video has a weight of 15MB or up to 50MB it works perfectly and is uploaded to Vimeo correctly.

I have seen that the same thing has happened to many people, but I am not sure how they have managed to solve it since the documentation is not 100% understandable to me, it is difficult for me. Maybe it's because I've been working for 12 hours and reading documentation that can probably help me.

I'm using this package: https://github.com/vimeo/laravel

My controller in the Store method is:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'file' => 'required',
    ]);

    $video = $request->file('file');
    Vimeo::upload($video);
}
```

I also found that one of the recommendations was to follow this documentation:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

So I tried it and so was my form.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{{ route('controller.store') }}">
    @csrf
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <input name="file" id="fileInput" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" disabled value="Send" />
</form>
```

Another step I took was to edit the .htaccess file by adding the following information.

```
memory_limit = 2048M
upload_max_filesize = 700M
upload_max_size = 700M
post_max_size = 700M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 1000
```

But it seems important to me to clarify that I'm working in my local environment.

Note: My Vimeo account is validated to upload videos from PHP SDK with ClientID, SecretId and Token.

[image: Vimeo Error]

So it stays when you don't load the video correctly and it can take hours and hours processing the video. It also throws me a 504 Gateway Time-out error on my server.

**I appreciate the help.
I even tried to upload everything through Ajax, but it was very difficult for me. (If someone can please give me an example of how to do it in another way, I will be very grateful)**

I am also using Laravel 6 with PHP 7.3

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: @RamūnasPabrėža Sometimes it says `Vimeo \ Exceptions \ VimeoUploadException
Unable to locate file to upload` and other times the video is loading (processing) for hours and hours.

Comment: Did you try modifying your `php.ini` file and then restarting the server?

Comment: Yes sir, but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong @AnisR.

Comment: Do you have more than one PHP version installed? If so, each PHP version has its own `php.ini` file, make sure you are modifying the right one.

Comment: @AnisR. I just realized that my version of PHP is not 7.3 but 7.4, and I only have one installed.